# Can't get string of variable in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database

I want to get the content of a news after the click to this link.

So, I tried with my code:

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', 'http://giaitri.vnexpress.net');

$news = $crawler->filter('#news_home > li');
$link = null;
$news = $crawler->filter('#news_home > li')->each(function($node) {
    $link = $node->filter('.txt_link');
    $child_news = $this->client->click($link->link());
    print_r($child_news->filter('#left_calculator')->text());
    if(!empty($child_news->filter('#left_calculator'))) {
        return [
        'title' => $link->text(),
        'link'  => $link->link()->getUri(),
        'thumbnail' => $node->filter('.txt_link img')->attr('src'),
        'description' => trim($node->filter('.news_lead')->text()),
        'content' => trim($child_news->filter('#left_calculator')->text()),
        ];
    }
});
```

`print_r($child_news->filter('#left_calculator')->text())` have values.

But in an array:

```
'content' => trim($child_news->filter('#left_calculator')->text()),
```

It show error like:

`The current node list is empty.`

Comment: Check condition with trim like     if(!empty($child_news->filter('#left_calculator')) && !empty(trim($child_news->filter('#left_calculator')))) {

Comment: Yes, I also add to my conditional. But seem not working. It shows like this: http://i.imgur.com/jtJWgNe.png.